# List(of T) sorting on a member of a custom class?

Tags: vb.net

How can I sort a list(of T) on one member (an Integer) where T is a custom data class?

```
Public Class CustomObject
   Public Property text1 as String
   Public Property counter1 as Integer
   Public Property counter2 as Integer
End Class

Public Objectlist As New List(Of CustomObject)

.add, .add, .add etc.

Objectlist.sort(???...)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [Sort overload which takes a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
ObjectList.Sort(Function(i,j) i.counter1.CompareTo(j.counter1))
```

Note that you can also use LINQ to return a new object:

```
 Dim sorted = ObjectList.OrderBy(Function(i) i.counter1)
```

---

If you need a decending sort, you can do:

```
ObjectList.Sort(Function(i,j) j.counter1.CompareTo(i.counter1))
```

Or:

```
 Dim sorted = ObjectList.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.counter1)
```

Comment: You are the BEST!  I would probably scare you if you knew how  many hours I've spent trying to make this happen...